# count the number of words with length $n$ using $a,b,c$ that contain odd number of $a$'s.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the words with length $n$ using $a,b,c$ that contain odd number of $a$'s.

**My attempt**:let $f_n$ be the answer of the question and $g_n$ the answer of the same question with even number of $a$'s.We have:

$f_n=2f_{n-1}+g_{n-1}$

$g_n=2g_{n-1}+f_{n-1}$

So we get:

$g_n-f_n=g_{n-1}-f_{n-1}=\dots =g_1-f_1=1$

$f_n+g_n=3(f_{n-1}+g_{n-1})$

So $2f_n+1=3(2f_{n-1}+1)$ and we have $f_n=3f_{n-1}+1$

But the book gave the answer $f_n=4f_{n-1}-3f_{n-2}$ So I need an answer containing that answer.

Comment: Hint: Your recurrence relation is correct. Just notice that $f_{n-1}=3f_{n-2}+1$. This recurrence relation is better because it provides a closed form solution of the form ${3^n-1}\over2$.

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi I need to get the answer$f_n=4f_{n-1}-3f_{n-2}$

Comment: Do you mean to say you need a combinatorial argument for the answer?

Comment: @SiddharthJoshi exactly.

Comment: If you don't mind, it would be a bit clearer to say "count the (number of) words" rather than "find the words", since you are looking for how many there are (not a list of all such words).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This combinatorial argument might be satisfactory:

Let $S$ be the set of all strings that have odd number of $a$ s.

Then the number of strings in $S$ that have $a$ in the first as well as the second place - $f_{n-2}$.

Other strings in $S$ have either $b$ or $c$ in the first place or the second place:

Number of strings in $S$ that have either $b$ or $c$ in the first place - $2f_{n-1}$.

Number of strings in $S$ that have either $b$ or $c$ in the second place - $2f_{n-1}$.

Number of strings in $S$ that have either $b$ or $c$ in both 
first and second place - $2\times2\times f_{n-2} = 4f_{n-2}$.

Using inclusion-exclsion principle, number of strings in $S$ that have either $b$ or $c$ in first or second place - $2f_{n-1}+2f_{n-1}-4f_{n-2} = 4(f_{n-1}-f_{n-2})$.

Thus total number of strings in $S$ - $f_n = 4(f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}) + f_{n-2} = 4f_{n-1}-3f_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $f_n-3f_{n-1}=1$. Also $f_{n-1}-3f_{n-2}=1$.
Subtract these, and you get $f_n-4f_{n-1}+3f_{n-2}=0$.

Comment: I need to get the answer $f_n=4f_{n-1}-3f_{n-2}$ directly using conmbinatorics