# count the number of words with length $n$ using $a,b,c$ that contain odd number of $a$'s and even number of $b$'s.

Tags: combinatorics

count the number of words with length $n$ using $a,b,c$ that contain odd number of $a$'s and even number of $b$'s.

I tried to use the same method that was [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347211/count-the-number-of-words-with-length-n-using-a-b-c-that-contain-odd-number) but it didn't work because in the first two letters we can't deal with the case $ab$ or $ba$.So how should I start?Any way I wan't the answer written in the book I mean:

$f_n=2f_{n-1}+3f_{n-2}$

Comment: Where did you get that recurrence relation from?

Comment: Correct relations are $$ f_n=2f_{n-1}+3f_{n-2}$$.  And/or $$ f_n=3f_{n-1}-1$$

Comment: Strike the second one - it should actually be $$ f_n=3f_{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1} $$

Comment: @WW1 Yes you are right.How to Prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $f_n$ denote the number of words of length $n$ that have odd number of $a$'s and even number of $b$'s.

Notice that the number of words of length $n$ that have even number of $a$'s and odd number of $b$'s is equal to number of words of length $n$ that have odd number of $b$'s and even number of $a$'s. This is because you can interchange $a$ and $b$ in any word and obtain a word of the other kind. (One-to-one correspondence)

Now I leave it to you verify that $f_n = 2f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}+2f_{n-2}+2f_{n-2}$.

Hint: $c \_ + \_ c - cc + aa + bb + ab + ba$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n$ be the number of such words of length $n$. Let us also consider the following sets:

1. $A=\{x:x\mbox{ is a word of $a$'s with odd length}\}$,
2. $B=\{x:x\mbox{ is a word of $b$'s with even length}\}$,
3. $C=\{x:x\mbox{ is a word of $c$'s}\}$,
4. $F=\{x:x\mbox{ is a word as requested}\}$.

So, every element of $F$ comes from a "mingling" of words of $A,B,C$. We will use the method of the exponential generating functions to calculate the wanted number.

Let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ be the numbers of elements of $A,B,C$ of length $n$, respectively. Then, it is evident that:

1. $a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \mbox{if $n$ is odd}\\0&\mbox{else}\end{array}\right.$,
2. $b_n=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \mbox{if $n$ is even}\\0&\mbox{else}\end{array}\right.$,
3. $c_n=1$

So, now we calculate the generating functions:

1. $$\begin{align*}A(x)=&\sum_{n\geq0}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=\text{odd}}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
   \end{align*}$$
2. $$\begin{align*}B(x)=&\sum_{n\geq0}b_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=\text{even}}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}
   \end{align*}$$
3. $$C(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$.

We know now that $F(x)=A(x)B(x)C(x)$, where $F(x)$ is the exponential generating function of $f_n$. So:
$$\begin{align*}F(x)=&\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}e^x=\frac{e^{3x}-e^{-x}}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(3x)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\right)=\\
=&\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{4}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}$$

On the other hand, $F(x)=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}f_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$, so, $f_n=\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{4}$.

As for the requested recursive relation, it must be changed to the following - which is easy to prove now that we have the formula:
$$f_n=3f_{n-1}+(-1)^n$$

**Notes**

1. As shown, the method of the exponential generating functions is a very useful tool in combinatorics.
2. The series that we used here are not treated in an "analytic" way, but as "algebraic" elements. By that, it is meant that we do not care about convergence and we do use power series as a way to "depict" sequences, where th $n$-th power of $x$ denotes the $n$-th term of the sequence. For instance, the power series $\sum\limits_{n\geq0}2^nx^n=\sum\limits_{n\geq0}(2x)^n$ is equivalent to the sequence $(1,2,4,8,16,\dots)$.

Comment: I changed the plus sign in the middle to a minus sign, but feel free to change this back if I made a mistake in doing so.

Comment: Oh, yeah! You' re right! Thank you! :)